# how to insert data from dynamic input with index to database

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a problem - I want to insert data to table column with ; from dynamic input

blade code:

```html
<td style="text-align: center">
    <div class="form-group">
        @for($i = 0; $i<$output; $i++)
            <input type="number_{{$i}}" style="border-color : gray ;"   id="test" value=""  name="test" class="form-control">
        @endfor
    </div>
</td>
```

Invoice controller code

```
   for ($l = 0; $l < count($request->input('number_' . $l . '_' . $l)); $l++) {
                $name = $name . $request->input('number_' .[$l] . '_' . $l)[$l] . ';';
            }

            $invoice->name =$name;
```

Comment: Sigh, the `type` attribute of the `<input>` element is not correct.  This is the type of input, and `name` is the name sent to the backend for that input.

Comment: <td style="text-align: center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @for($i = 0; $i<$output; $i++)
                                            <input type="number" style="border-color : gray ;"   id="test" value=""  name="number_{{$i}}" class="form-control">
                                        @endfor
                                    </div>
                                    </td>

Comment: same proble i think the problem is from controller code

Comment: You might be better off creating an array of `number[]` for your name, and you can iterate through that instead of using a variable name.

Comment: can you tell me how exactly i do it